# Does the relation V₁/V₂=N₁/N₂ apply for any transformers whatever the efficiency?

Tags: transformer

Does the relation V₁/V₂=N₁/N₂ apply for any transformers whatever the efficiency? And if it only applies to those of 100% efficiency then how can I make it apply for those of efficiency less than that?

Comment: Did your newly accepted answer provide answers to both your questions? And note what I said at the end of the previously accepted answer: *There may be other things you can do if you explained what you are trying to achieve.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the formula for an ideal transformer (no losses at all, neither electric not magnetic). Sadly, ideals transformers don't exist. So it aplies to no transforem you can buy or build.

But it's a close enough aproximation for most rel life scenarios to use as a starting point.

So what kind of losses are there?

- Non perfect magnetic coupling
- magnetisation losses
- ohmic losses in primary and secondary windings
- saturation losses in the core
- capacitive effects

The list is not complete, it's just from the top of my head. The easiest is probably the ohmic losses because they are linear to the current in the winding (more current = more voltage drop). The rest is non linear stuff that's really hard to calculate.

On the bright side: in most AC applications it doesn't matter that much.

Answer (score 3):

> *Does the relation V₁/V₂=N₁/N₂ apply for any transformers whatever the
> efficiency?*

The formula only applies to perfectly coupled primary and secondary windings that are wound with 0 Ω resistance wire on a core that does not saturate or produce losses.

> *how can I make it apply for those of efficiency less than that?*

You can't but, you can compensate for load current causing output voltage reduction (due to non 100% coupling). There may be other things you can do if you explained what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So there is no way one can tell N₂ given N₁, V₁, and V₂ and given that the transformer isn't 100% efficient, right?

Comment: Strictly speaking no. If you want to characterize a transformer in terms of its [equivalent circuit](http://www.stades.co.uk/Transformer/transformer%20equivalent%20circuit.PNG) then you need to perform an open secondary test on full primary voltage and a shorted secondary test on full secondary current. For high-frequency transformers it's more difficult due to parasitic capacitance.